# Brahma, Brahman, Brahmin, and Atman?

Tags: hinduism

In Hinduism and Indian philosophy, what is the difference between Brahma, Brahman, Brahmin, and Atman?

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! You may want to add in some detail as to why this question is interesting for you; how far have you explored Indian Philosophy, for example; or what's motivated you to ask this question ie your specific concern.

Comment: Right now, I'm in an Asian Philosophy course; we're reading an introduction to Hinduism through Huston Smith's World Religions. He mentions all four concepts above, but he doesn't explicitly delineate the difference and commonality between the concepts above.

Comment: there is a separate hindu stack exchange, for you to consider for future hindu question (christianity, islam, judaism, buddhism and hinduism have their own stack exchanges).

Comment: In addition to these answers, you can get [a more detailed etic answer here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma#Difference_between_Brahma.2C_Brahman.2C_Brahmin_and_Brahmanas)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In his commentary on the *Brahma Sutras*, the *Sri-Bhasya*, Ramanuja says:

> The word Brahman is derived from the root '*brh*' which denotes greatness, and is therefore applicable to all objects which have the quality of greatness, but more aptly to that object which by nature and qualities possesses this greatness to an infinite degree...

Brahman is not a name, but rather a way to refer to the Absolute, the Supreme Reality of the Vedanta philosophy.

The word Brahma can refer to two things depending upon where it is being used. First, Brahma is the first being created with every new cycle. All beings in a particular cycle are created by Brahma. A different soul becomes Brahma in every new cycle. Brahma is a god, but the gods are office holders so to speak and new souls take the stations in every new cycle. Second, Brahma is one of the three gods making up the Hindu trinity, called the Trimurti, which can be thought of as Brahman (Isvara). Brahma, Vishnu, and Siva make up the trinity and stand for the creative, sustainer, and destroyer aspects of the Godhead.

Brahmin refers to a person who belongs to the priest caste, the highest caste in Hindu society.

Atman is the soul of man. According to the Advaita Vedanta philosophy the soul of man is one with and the same as Brahman. When Brahman within an individual is referred to, it is referred to as the Atman. Thus Atman = Brahman. There are differences between what is meant by 'soul' in Hindu philosophy and Christian philosophy. Swami Vivekananda says (*Complete Works*, V6, p 85):

> One of the chief distinctions between the Vedic and Christian religion is that the Christian religion teaches that each human soul has its beginning at its birth into this world; whereas the Vedic religion asserts that the spirit of man is an emanation of the Eternal Being and had no more a beginning than God Himself.

A person has an individual 'soul' (in Hinduism - the *jiva*) that survives death and is the 'soul' that passes from one birth to another. The innermost part of the soul is the atman. For a more detailed description see my answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attached-to-the-body

For a good description of the the Atman see the following link. There are 2 lectures under the topic *Jnana Yoga*, titled *The Atman* and *The Atman:Its Bondage and Freedom* - http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_2/vol_2_frame.htm

Comment: Just to clarify: are you saying that the innermost part of *jiva* is *atman*?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Yes. The atman is manifested in the vijnanamayakosa which is one of three kosas that make up the subtle body or jiva.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Let me clarify my last comment a little more. Jiva is embodied soul, whether in embodied in the gross or subtle body. Depending upon the whether you are talking monism, qualified monism, or dualism, and the commentator, the jiva can have different interpretations.

Comment: This answer seems good but is a little misleading imo. In advaita there would be no individual soul and Brahman would be a rather more subtle idea, especially the idea of the two Brahman. Best to read an authoritative text than ask on a forum.  ,  . .

Comment: @PeterJ Advaita says that there is only one soul. You have misunderstood the use of the word soul. There is no 'soul' in Hinduism or Advaita. Soul is a Christian concept. There are 'jivas' which are the subtle body which holds the Atman and goes from one material existence to the next. There are not 2 Brahmans. There is only one Brahman. You are tripping over the English translation of Sanskrit. The masculine Brahma (with diacritical) is used in Sanskrit it refers to the the creator of the cycle. When the neutral Brahma (no diacritical) is used, it refers to the English Brahman.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - I'd agree with your comment on the soul (I didn't mean to suggest otherwise) but not on the two Brahman. Of course they are not two,but the idea is useful and appears in literature from time to time. I would connect it loosely with the two Taos - the one we can talk about and the one we cannot. I see this as a useful conceptual device, not an ontological claim. Is this better?

Comment: @peterj Yes I agree. In Vedanta there is what is referred to as the Nirguna Brahman (Brahman without attributes) and the Saguna Brahman (Brahman with attributes). We cannot 'sense' the Nirguna Brahman as we are limited by our own senses. We can sense the Saguna Brahman. You might like to read the section titled "Adhyasa or Superimposition" here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62753.html

Comment: @PeterJ But 'they' are not two, 'they' are One alone.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - Ha. I could even argue against the statement 'they are One' since there is no 'they'. But yes, they are One. No argument frim me.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - And thanks for the excellent reference.

Answer (score 5):

- **Brahma** is one of the main Hindu deities.
- **Brahman** is an abstract concept with a wide meaning. One of its meaning is a hypothetical principle of the universe.
- A **Brahmin** is a member of the first of the four classes.
- **Atman** again has a wide meaning. One meaning is similar to soul. The main statement of the Indian upanishads is the equation "atman = brahman". That's difficult to understand. But a good metaphor for it is Indra's net, even when the latter is from Buddhism. 
  See Gail Atkins figure and the five bullet points below at http://awakeningtoreality.blogspot.de/2009/04/net-of-indra.html

Comment: I am sympathetic to some ideas in Hinduism and in particular those of Brahman and Atman, but that page on Indira's net that you linked to contains in my opinion the most gobbledygook I have seen in one place since a long long time...

Comment: and I don't think Atman=Brahman is too difficult to grasp - it is reminiscent of monism, or idealism, or panpsychism - something along the lines of the essence of mind is an essence of the universe.

Comment: @nir I refer only to the figure of GAIL ATKINS and the five bullet points below. - I agree with your last sentence: atman = brahman is meant as "something along the lines of the essence of mind is an essence of the universe". But what is the essence of the mind, what is the essence of the universe, why are they equal, and how to show that they are? - I did never understand what Hindus explained to me about these points. I appreciated Indra's net as a metaphor to find at least some sense in the grand unification of the Upanishads.

Comment: I quite like the picture that's drawn of Indras net; it's so rather like Liebniz's monads, that I've wondered before whether he had been in part inspired by it; the Upanishads are great.

Comment: This answer lacks specificity. "Brahma is one of the main Hindu deities." Which one? "A Brahmin is a member of the first of the four classes." As characterized by what?

Comment: @Rubellite Fae You find the other gods of the trimurti in the answer of John Slegers. - You find a characterisation of the four varnas (classes) in the Bhagavad Gita 18,41ff.

Answer (score 2):

#### Brahmin

The Hindu caste system has four [Varna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varna_(Hinduism)) :

- [Brahmins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmin): priests, scholars and teachers
- [Kshatriyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshatriya): rulers, warriors and administrators
- [Vaishyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishya): agriculturalists and merchants
- [Shudras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shudra): laborers and service providers

The Brahmin caste are thus the caste that produced the [clergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clergy) in traditional Hindu society.

---

#### Brahma

Hinduism has three primary Gods, known as the [Trimurti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimurti). These Gods are references to the three primary forces in nature that hold the universe together :

- [Brahma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma) (order), the source of creation, can be understood as an anthropomorphic representation of [emergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence)
- [Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva) (chaos), the source of destruction, can be understood as an anthropomorphic representation of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy)
- [Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu) (balance), the source of balance, can be understood as an anthropomorphic representation of [the laws of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics)

Brahma is thus the Hindu representation of the creative force in the universe.

---

#### Atman & Brahman

The [Atman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_(Hinduism)) and [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman) are concepts from the [Vedanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta) branch of Hinduism that represent respectively your [individual consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness) and [universal consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_mind). The Brahman is thus a [pantheistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism) perspective on the divine.

[Advaita Vedanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta), a school of thought within the Vedanta branch, stresses the notion that the Atman and Brahman are just different manifestations of the same divine essence, which is basically just simplified [Animism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animism).

See also my article [The Atheistic approach to God… or how to bridge the gap between Atheists and Theists](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-atheistic-approach-to-god-5ae3f2b0012b) where I explain how Atheism, Pantheism, Hinduism, Animism and Shamanism are really just different perspectives on the same core concepts.

Comment: How you get from Advaita Vedanta to Animism I cannot imagine. The correct term is 'nondualism'. This states that the Universe is a Unity or Consciousness is a Unity. This view is not strictly atheism or theism, which is why we find both in the perennial philosophy. Nor is Atman defined as our individual consciousness but as something more like 'Christ-consciousness'.  .

Comment: @PeterJ : I'm not sure what "Christ-consciousness" is supposed to mean. Even though I've been raised a Catholic, that term means literally nothing to me. Anyway, the Animistic position is that (1) everything in the universe is conscious to some degree and that (2) consciousness is layered like a [Matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll). The Atman & Brahman correspond with two layers within such an Animistic framework. See [my article](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-atheistic-approach-to-god-5ae3f2b0012b) for more details on how Hinduism relates to Animism!

Comment: I'm not sure which of us is right about this since 'animism' take slghtly different forms. . Aurobindo speaks of 'inconscient' matter and this supports the view that while for the Upanishads everything is in consciousness it need not follow that everything is conscious, (Thus many idealists deny panpsychism), But I will go and read your article. 'Christ-consciousness' would equate with Atman and is a common phrase for those who interpret Jesus as teaching the the nondual doctrine, for instance readers of 'A Course in Miracles',

Comment: Why does the '@name' not appear at the start of my comments? It keeps happening and refuses to be show up even when I edit.

Comment: @PeterJ : The `@name` is automatically removed if your comment is directed to author of the answer you're commenting on, because that author will always receive a notification. Anyway, the difference between "everying being in consciousness" and "everying being conscious" seems rather arbitrary to me. Also, your explanation of "Christ-consciousness" still sounds like gibberish to me.

Comment: Thanks John. The distinction I made is important.  An image of consciousness may not be conscious so 'in' consciousness but not an example of it. It's an old debate in idealism as to whether this distinction is necessary. It's important because one definition would allow a person to be a metaphysical materialist yet also a panpsychist. It takes some doing but some people do endorse this position.  You could google 'Christ-consciousness' for a longer description. If the discussion seems odd it may because you're equating 'Atman' with the individual consciousness or mind. .

Comment: @PeterJ : If I have a picture of a chair in my mind, then that chair may not be part of my consciousness... but the picture of that chair sure is. I can't think of anything, really, that exists in the conscious mind without being part of it. Anyway, I'm a monist myself and I reject the dualism between the material and the spiritual as being a mere illusion. And based on the following source, no one agrees on the definition of "Christ-consciousness", making it an impractical term -> http://goldenageofgaia.com/spiritual-essays/cross-cultural-spirituality/what-is-christ-consciousness/

Comment: LOL! I would suggest avoiding websites such as that one. if your monism is of the nondual type then we share it. It is this world-view that speaks about Christ-consciousness since all others would reject the possibility. Ordinary monism would have to reject it, but the Upanishadic form, for which all distinctions are false, would say that it is our birthright.

Comment: @PeterJ "if your monism is of the nondual type"  Please clear up how monism can be anything other than nondual. John Slegers, "Christ consciousness" is an ACIM term for "true self" as opposed to "ego 'self.'" They call it that because Yeshua ben Yosef is the West's most famous example of an individual who identified self with true self instead of ego. ACIM is somewhat like Advaita Vedanta for former Christians. Although, most diligent readers I've met have a hard time understanding the texts.

Comment: @Rubellite Fae - We seem to be on the same page. In most of its forms monism is dualism.in disguise. For instance, materialism is sometimes called monism because it reduces mind to matter, but clearly it is nothing like advaita. The point would be that monism says 'one' while nondualism says 'not-two'. The latter is less prone to be misunderstood.as a numerical 'one'.  I'd say ACIM simply is Christianity rather than being for former Christians but as you say, It's a very tough text for anyone new to this world-view. It's tough for anyone.

Comment: @PeterJ : `"Western philosophy is traditionally concerned with contrasting one grid with another grid, and amending grids in hopes of finding a perfect one that will account for all reality and will, hence, (say unenlightened westerners) be true. This is illusory; it is what we Erisians call the Aneristic Illusion. Some grids can be more useful than others, some more beautiful than others, some more pleasant than others, etc., but none can be more True than any other." — Malaclypse the Younger, Principia Discordia`

Comment: @PeterJ "In most of its forms monism is dualism.in disguise. ... clearly it is nothing like advaita." You still haven't really explained. That was more of a repetition. "monism says 'one' while nondualism says 'not-two'." So, 3, 7, 1/9, -5? Those are all non-two. Perhaps we should take this discussion to the chat room? "I'd say ACIM simply is Christianity rather than being for former Christians" Good point. The practitioners whom I know turned away from Christianity before finding ACIM. It might be **for** Christians, but it is actually closer to what Yeshua taught than Christianity is.

Comment: @RubelliteFae : The point I'm trying to make, is that the divine can be represented in a `monastic` fashion (eg. God = the universe), a `dualistic` fashion (eg. good vs evil or mind vs matter), a `trinity` (eg. order, chaos & balance) or a `fractal` (eg. Hinduism's Devas & Shinto's Kami). Each of these are just different perspectives on the same conception of the fundamental nature of the universe, focusing on different characteristics.

Comment: @Rubelite Fae - Pardon me. Monism is dualism because it would be logically impossible for only one thing to exist. Thus Democtritus needs Atom and Void and can go no further with his materialistic reduction. To exist a thing must stand-out from its background and this is two things. For this reason the sages are very careful to regularly insist that Unity of the Universe should not imply a numerical 'one' but a transcendence of number and form. 'Monism' is sometimes is used to describe this view but it is much safer to call it non-dualism. The longer answer would be, well, long.   .

Comment: @PeterJ : It is illogically for only two things to exist either... or for only three things to exist. However, it is perfectly logical for trillions upon trillions of things to exist with various degrees of complexity, all sharing the same fundamental essence. And that is a monistic position shared by Pantheists & Animists alike. Personally, I consider myself a Pantheistic Animist & I 100% reject dualism as a mere illusion.

Comment: @John Stegers-  Yes! and also no. I would say it is illogical for anything to exist since our usual idea of existence is illogical, as we know from metaphysics. Also, that the idea of 'essence' is a mistake. So, I don't share your monism. But it looks like our views are close

Comment: @PeterJ : If the scientific method allows us to detect and measure it, it exists within the objective reality we live in. However, we can't tell what exactly the fundamental nature of that objective reality really is. It sure seems not that different from a hologram or a virtual reality, which begs the question whether we are really nothing but the virtual reality of another universe. That question, however, is unanswerable as far as I know.

Comment: @John Slegers - I believe all these questions are answerable and have been answered. Would not your solution lead to an infinite regress of universes? (The same problem the script-writers met in the Matrix).

Comment: @PeterJ : Personally I lean towards the notion that dimensions are circular instead of linear and that our universe is sort-of like a fractal.

Comment: @PeterJ "Monism is dualism because it would be logically impossible for only one thing to exist."  It is logically possible for only one thing to exist in varying degrees. "To exist a thing must stand-out from its background" You are comparing the existence of a thing to the non-existence of a thing. Non-existence doesn't exist, so it doesn't need to be considered a "thing." Only the existing exists, thus monism. Linguistically, "Monism" means one-ism. Non-dualism means, not-two-ism. 3 is not two, 0 is not two, -2 is not two, 1/2 is not two. Many things are not two. Only 1 is 1.

Comment: Also, I again propose this conversation be moved to the chat room, as it isn't pertinent to the question.

Comment: @Rubelite Fae - I agree about moving it. But a last comment - you cannot casually redefine 'exist' . It means 'stand-out' to most people. Do you not see that 'exist/not-exist' is two states? Nondualism rejects the idea of two states and would call it dualism. The topic is too big for the text-boxes here. . .

Comment: @John Slegers - Yes! This is weird. On another forum I recently posted a explanation of why I see dimensions as being circular, like the worm Aurobourus, and not open-ended, and linked this to Hofstadter's 'strange loops'. We must be on the same track.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was too long for a comment.

At hinduism.stackexchange.com you will get emic answers to this question. Here the answers are more likely to be etic. As a side note, as a linguaphile I discourage concurrently learning words that either sound similar or have totally opposite meanings. In my experience, I forget or am apprehensive about which is which. Whatever your study and memorization methodology is, I'd recommend learning other things in between or risk losing certainty about the meaning of these words.

These answers will be short enough to memorize and further research, but are in no way comprehensive. Volumes have been written on these topics.

**Brahman**: the totality of the cosmos; the (non-anthropomorphic) monad; Ultimate Reality, i.e., that which lies behind the veil of *maya* (useful illusion).
**Brahma**: the deva of creation (and thus anthropomorphic); often spoken of in context of the *trimurti*—creation, preservation, destruction; the generative aspects of reality.
**Brahmin**: a social caste whose members have the *dharma* (sacred life-duty) of theology.
**Atman**: similar to the Western concept of the individual soul; often discussed along with Brahman: dualistic schools believe it is different/separate from Brahman (like traditional Western religions) while non-dualistic schools believe that any seeming differentiation/separation is *maya* (like Western esoteric/mysticism schools).

Answer (score 1):

Satcitananda.
Roughly: truth, consciousness, bliss.

That's it.  Not surprisingly however, Satcitananda has a Wikipedia!   And I would particularly draw your attention to the Discussion section of the Wikipedia article.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satcitananda

I was trying to get across that it is something realized rather than learned through definitions (as we tend to do in the west). Brahman "is" indescribable, unitary, ultimate (wiki, under the Vedanta section).

I realize that what I have written here does not answer the original question as asked, and again I would point to the discussion section I mentioned above.

Comment: This is too brief for an answer here. Can you expand it? See [answer].

Comment: I fear any answer would be too brief. This stuff takes years to assimilate and as Gordon says, some meditation would be required for any proper understanding. Put simply, the Universe would be a Unity and all distinctions including Brahman-Atman would be conceptual. Even 'here-there' and 'now-then' would be mental constructs to be transcended by the practices of Yoga. What is revealed is our true self, and ultimately this would be Being, Consciousness, Bliss, or in Christian terms the Godhead. This would be what we are and we'd know this if only we could see past the smoke and mirrors.